# ¿Por qué no elimina todas las filas seleccionadas?

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Cuando quiero **eliminar varias filas seleccionadas de una tabla**, tengo un problema con que elimina todas menos una -aleatoriamente: ni la primera marcada ni la última marcada-, **elimina TODAS menos una.**

Si selecciono una fila, la elimina perfectamente.

¿Dónde está el error?

**Código:**

```
private void button_eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tabla_clientes.getModel();

        int fila = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRow();
        if (fila < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar al menos un cliente.");
        } else if (fila >= 0) {
            int confirmado = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Deseas eliminar los clientes?", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == confirmado){
                int[] filasselec  = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRows();
                for (int i=0; i<filasselec.length; i++){
                    String dni_a_eliminar = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(i, 0);
                    Conexiones.eliminar_cliente(dni_a_eliminar);
                    modelo.removeRow(filasselec[i]);
               }
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Borrado realizado con éxito.");
               label_contador.setText("Hay "+Conexiones.contar_clientes()+" clientes registrados.");
            }
        }
    }

public static void eliminar_cliente(String DNI){
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        try (PreparedStatement stm = c.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM clientes WHERE dni = ?")) {
            //Consulta para eliminar un cliente en la base de datos.
            //String eliminar_clientes = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE dni = '" + DNI + "';";
            stm.setString(1, DNI);
            int resultado1 = 1;
            //System.out.println(eliminar_clientes);
            resultado1 = stm.executeUpdate();
            if(resultado1<=0){
                throw new SQLException();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Cliente eliminado de la tabla clientes.");
            }
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Borrado realizado con éxito.");
            //c.commit();
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                c.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar `String dni_a_eliminar = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 0);` en vez de `String dni_a_eliminar = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(i, 0);`? Parece que estás tratando de obtener los `ids` consecutivos de las filas, no los que fueron seleccionados.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Me sigue sin funcionar. Selecciono 3 usuarios, me elimina 2 aunque en la consola Output me sale 3 veces "Cliente eliminado correctamente". Osea me aparece 3 veces el mensaje de la funciona eliminar_cliente pero en la tabla no lo elimina.

Comment: A parte del cambio que te propuse, ¿probaste a borrar las filas de la última a la primera? Lo digo porque los índices cambiarían durante el borrado. Te lo pongo en la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La posición de la fila desde la que quieres obtener el `id` no se está obteniendo correctamente en el bucle:

```
/* Para que el borrado no interfiera con los índices hacemos el bucle al revés */
for (int i = filasselec.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  /* Debes obtener el "id" de la fila seleccionada, no del orden del bucle */
  String dni_a_eliminar = (String) tabla_clientes.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 0);
  Conexiones.eliminar_cliente(dni_a_eliminar);
  /* Esta parte, sin embargo, la tenías bien */
  modelo.removeRow(filasselec[i]);
}
```

Además, es recomendable recorrer el bucle al revés para que el reordenado de los elementos tras borrarlos no afecte al funcionamiento.

Comment: Funciona correctamente. No se me había ocurrido recorrer el for al revés. ;)